# Randomnly select numbers from a list with a condition

Tags: python, list, random

I have a `list(range(30000))`. I need to randomnly select numbers inside it such that, it takes a certain count of numbers say `'n'` in total at the same time it should take `'k'` number of values between two index positions.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,,6,7,8......20,21,22......88,89.....30k]
```

I need to select `5000` numbers in total. `'x'` numbers between `0th index to 100th index`, `'y'` numbers between `100 to 200` etc.

There is no hard rule that it should select `5000` numbers itself. But it should sure lie between `0-100, 100-200` etc.

I saw `random.choice` but how to give it a condition

To put the question accurately: I need `50` numbers from `0-100,200-300 etc.`

Comment: Choose first the numbers in the specific intervals, then the remaining ones among the remaining numbers. It would have been possible to give you a more accurate answer if you had asked a more accurate question.

Comment: Are the intervals and amount of numbers in each interval constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to approach this:

```
import random
# define the sample size of each interval
# or for your specific case generate a sequence
# that adds up to 5000
size = [5, 2, 10]
n = 300
step = 100

# iterate over both a range (or sequence) and size
# and take random samples accordingly
out = [random.sample(list(range(i-step,i)), k) 
               for i, k in zip(range(step, n+step, step), size)]
```

---

```
print(out)
[[6, 86, 96, 62, 53], [115, 176], [245, 259, 297, 249, 225, 281, 264, 274, 275, 206]]
```

Comment: So if I have just one size (say 50) , I have to create a list like size = [50,50,50...] etc.? is  there some other work around?

Comment: The way I see it is that you'll have to sample from each subsequence independenlty. There's no way that I know of using `random` or similar libraries to add such constraint @RAMSHANKERG

Comment: Ah sure Yatu, I would i was just waiting if i could get a better answer..! yours has done the job! just in case! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script that does exactly what you asked for.

```
import random
a = 0
b=100
l = list()
for z in range(149):
    a = a+200
    b = b+200
    for x in range(50):
        l.append(random.randint(a,b))
```